# Can I install packages/drivers from older releases of Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, apt, touchpad, chromebook

Can I, running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, install, say, a driver for Ubuntu 14.04?

I'm running Ubuntu on a Parrot Chromebook and the touchpad doesn't work and neither do the F1-12 keys when I'm not holding down function. I know I can fix the touchpad with [these](https://github.com/hugegreenbug/xf86-input-cmt) drivers but there isn't a [repo](http://ppa.launchpad.net/hugegreenbug/cmt/ubuntu/dists/) for Xenial. There's only devel, saucy, trusty, and utopic. I want to know if installing the driver from one of the other repos would work or if it would mess something up.

Also, I'm ***very*** new to Ubuntu and don't understand apt pinning so, if that is the **best** way to do this, then could someone break it down so it's very simple?

Comment: https://twitter.com/hugegreenbug  is the twitter account of the maintainer. Why not ask him for a possible update? :)

Comment: Regarding compatibility: Between 2 LTS releases: NO. Most unlikely.  Between the LTS and the normal releases: YES. With exceptions. A LTS gets the hardware stacks of all the normal releases after it.

Answer (score 0):

download the package from the repo that has it.

remove the not working driver: `sudo apt-get remove <package name>`

then run:  `sudo dpkg -i <file name>`.

if you can satisfy all the dependencies of the package without creating a conflict with a newer package, the the older package will run just fine.

you can get a compiled package here https://launchpad.net/~hugegreenbug/+archive/ubuntu/cmt

Comment: I guess he would need to uninstall the dysfunctional driver or have a way to switch

Comment: yes of course, edited my answer to include it

Comment: stop editing my answer, installing from a file instead of the package list requires the file name not the package name. if he uses the package name it will put the nonworking new driver back in that he just removed.